# Get jsp output in spring controller as String

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Isn't there any easy way in Spring 4 by which we can achieve same as following code

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/account_summary.jsp").include(request, response);
```

To get output of a JSP file as a String in our controller. Presently I am using following code for this purpose

```
HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
    private final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return new PrintWriter(sw);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return sw.toString();
    }
};
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/account_summary.jsp").include(request, responseWrapper);
```

I need output of JSP in a String so I can build a JSON object to return back. But I am not able to find a spring only solution to achieve this.

Comment: You want to return the HTML inside JSON for updating the DOM from an AJAX call?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, not just html, there are some other fields as well that I am passing with JSON

Comment: The way you have seems fine. For much better results (IMO), use a templating library like Thymeleaf or Velocity.